# Regex search specific word start and finish with accent

Tags: javascript, regex, diacritics

I have a problem with my code, it doesn't found words beginning or finishing with a accent letter why ? how to resolve this problem ?
thank you for your answer.

```
var regex = /\bégalité\b/gui;
var paragraph = 'Une égalité parfaite';
var matched = paragraph.match(regex);
console.log(matched);
```

Comment: `\b` word boundaries are not Unicode aware. You may use XRegExp to build a regex with custom word boundaries though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with Regex and the \b (assert position at a word boundary) matches the beginning of a string with a starting character out of the normal 256-byte range.

You can try using:

```
(?:^|\s)
```

instead.

This uses a non-capturing group which matches the beginning of a string OR whitespace.

Comment: var regex = new XRegExp('(^|\\s)' + item + '(?=\\s|$)', 'gu');